# NGRX Cannot access 'USER_FEATURE' before initialization

Tags: ngrx, angular12

I currently have this:

user.state.ts

```
export interface IFeatureUserState {
  checkoutRow: IEntityState<CheckoutRow>;
...
};

export const USER_FEATURE = 'users';
export const userFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<IFeatureUserState>(
  USER_FEATURE
);

export const userReducers: ActionReducerMap<IFeatureUserState> = {
  checkoutRow: checkoutRowReducer,
...
};
```

user-store.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forFeature(USER_FEATURE, userReducers),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([
         CheckoutRowEffects,
...
   NgrxAutoEntityModule.forFeature();

  providers: [
    { provide: CheckoutRow, useClass: EntityService },
...
]);
```

user-layout.module.ts <- Lazy loaded module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    UserStoreModule
...
]
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    StoreModule.forRoot({}, {
      metaReducers: [clearState],
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true,
      },
    }),
    AuthStoreModule, // Another feature with same setup as USER_FEATURE but with authentication models.
    EffectsModule.forRoot(),
    NgrxAutoEntityModule.forRoot(),
...
});
```

However i get this error:

[image]

Anyone know what i do wrong? My goal is to use NGRX with features and separate my store into 2 modules, one for root/auth handling and one for user store functionality.

Comment: Could you please write (in the question) the full list of imports within the mentioned modules, so we can help you to fix this error?

Comment: Are you trying to access your user state in your auth store?

Comment: Circular dependencies caused the error for me.

Comment: Getting same error. Any solution so far?

Answer (score 1):

my problem solved by moving

```
export const USER_FEATURE = 'users';
```

to {nameof}actions.ts